# Importing pictures from module in Python

Tags: python, scikit-image

Very stupid question, but here it goes.

Scikit-image has a module called 'data'. Such module has plenty of pictures that are used in the examples.

So, for instance:

```
from skimage import data
image = data.camera() # camera being a camera.png file in data
```

Now, I want to import my own files into the scripts, but if I add a new file to the data folder, I get back the following error:

> module data has no attribute 'whatever' #whatever being the new file I added to data.

Comment: `data` is a python module. You'd need to edit some Python code to make it work, unless it's doing something clever with attribute lookups, but I doubt it.

Comment: The [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.data.html) says you can use [**`data.imread`**](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.data.html#skimage.data.imread) to read any image file, or [**`data.load`**](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.data.html#load) to load an image from the data directory.

Comment: Peter, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution with respect to @Peter Wood's comment, [`skimage.io.imread`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) should do the trick:

```
In [5]: from skimage import io

In [6]: image = io.imread('whatever.png')

In [7]: io.imshow(image)
Out[7]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0xf695f98>
```

[image: whatever]